# Add user to admin Group using powershell 3.0

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add user to administrators group but this script is not working in powershell 3.0

```
 Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators'   -Member 'domain\user'
```

this script run on windows 2016 server but not working on windows 2008 server
Please anyone know How to add user in Administrators group using powershell 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command (Local User):

```
net localgroup Administrators username /add
```

To add a domain user:

```
net localgroup Administrators Domain\username /add
```

Windows server 2008 dosen't have `Add-LocalGroupMember` so you need to use `net.exe` for this. Works in all Windows Server editions 2003 to 2019.